# mod_rewrite to insert directory in dynamic URLs?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, directory

I am looking for a way to write a mod_rewrite in order to insert a directory into an URL? I want to redirect old URLs to new URLs like so:

old URL: http://www.domain.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=128468

new URL: http://www.domain.com**/forum**/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=128468

I would like this to work for all values of 'f' and 't'. Thanks!

Comment: After researching I tried the following, but it does not work?

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum/

RewriteRule ^viewtopic.php$ /forum/viewtopic.php [L,R=301]
`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /viewtopic
RewriteRule ^viewtopic\.php$ /forum/viewtopic\.php [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

1. The first line checks that /forum/ is NOT already present in the URI.
2. The second line checks that /viewtopic is present in the URI.
3. the third line replaces viewtopic.php with /forum/viewtopic.php